# ggrepel remove line around labels

Tags: r, ggrepel

How can I remove the line around `geom_label_repel`. Using `label.size = 0` appears to have no visible effect. I could set `colour

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = wt)) +
  geom_point(color = 'red') +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = rownames(mtcars)), label.size = 0, fill = "white") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

Entering a `geom_text_repel` after a blank `geom_label_repel` occasionally works, but is not reliable: the boxes may appear in a different location to the text.

[image]

Comment: `label.size=0` gets rid of the borders when I run your code.

Comment: They're visible, but very small. (When I save it as a PDF, for example, they're clearly visible in some viewers.)

Comment: How about if you do `label.size=NA`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As eipi10 noted in the comment, set `label.size=NA`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = wt)) +
  geom_point(color = 'red') +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = rownames(mtcars)), label.size = NA, fill = "white") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can omit the label boxes using the `geom_text_repel` geom.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = wt)) +
  geom_point(color = 'red') +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)

g + geom_label_repel(aes(label = rownames(mtcars)), fill = "white")
```

[image]

```
g + geom_text_repel(aes(label = rownames(mtcars)))
```

[image]

Also, according to the help page:

> Currently `geom_label_repel` ... is considerably slower than `geom_text_repel`.